# Is it possible to create ionic2 project with cordova-windows@5.0.0 instead of the current cordova-windows@4.4.3?

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-win10

I need this because I am trying to problem in adding sqlite plugin to the project and compile for windows 10 platform. And according to research this is a [bug in Cordova-windows 4.4.3 that was resolved to version 5.0.0.](https://github.com/apache/cordova-windows/pull/219)

More by applying the command `ionic platform add windows` to add the windows platform the added platform is the 4.4.3:

```
> ...
> Windows project created with cordova-windows@4.4.3
> ...
```

So how could I make version [`cordova-windows@5.0.0`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-windows/releases/tag/5.0.0) used to create the project for the **windows platform**?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, add this line to config.xml:

```
<engine name="windows" spec="5.0.0" />
```

also you might want to specify the target version, for instance:

```
<preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
```