# How to install ionic - I get "npm ERR! path" and other errors

Tags: windows, ionic-framework, npm

please help :)

How do I install IONIC on Windows. For some random reason it doesn't install.

I have installed Node, NPM and Cordova.

But I get errors when I try to install IONIC.

Here is my log:

So, the problem is that I can't install ionic.

**C:\Windows\system32>ionic**

'ionic' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Windows\system32>npm -v

4.4.2

C:\Windows\system32>cordova -v

6.5.0

C:\Windows\system32>node -v

v6.10.0

**C:\Windows\system32>npm install -g ionic**

npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead

npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.3.3: Use uuid module instead
C:\Users\jasonbullen\AppData\Roaming\npm `-- (empty)

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\ionic\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):

npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@ 1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}
)

npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of mime-types with mime-types@ 2.0.14

npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of semver with semver@4.2.0

npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of cross-spawn with cross-spawn@4.0.2

npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of form-data with form-data@0.2.0

npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of request with request@2.51.0

npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of ionic-app-lib with ionic-app-lib@2.2.0

**npm ERR! path C:\Users\jasonbullen\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\ans
i-b577a3a1**

npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\jasonbullen\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\ansi-b577a3a1' -> 'C:\Users\jasonbullen\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\ansi'

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\jasonbullen\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\ansi-b577a3a1' -> 'C:\Users\jasonbullen\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\ansi'

npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself

npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.

npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\jasonbullen\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-03-23T09_44_06_598Z-debug.log

Many Thanks :)

Please help people - it still doesn't work :(

Comment: any approach that your have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be able to solve after update the npm module and install ionic globally

```
npm cache clean -f
npm install -g npm 
npm uninstall -g ionic cordova
npm cache clean -f
npm install -g ionic cordova
```

If problem still persist

```
npm install -g minimatch
```

Issue refer to https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/13323

Answer (score 0):

add windows platform by running:

```
ionic platform add windows
```

or alternatively

add this to your config.xml:

```
<engine name="windows" spec="5.0.0" />
```

and run `ionic prepare`
see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42815110/5239171